# Drupal: Invalid Propery Value on region background image in CSS

Tags: css, drupal, background

I'm creating a theme for a drupal site, it is very basic so far.  The folder structure of the theme is like so:

```
theme-folder
-->css
   -->style.css
-->images
   -->first_page_slideshow.png
--drupal files--
```

The css for the region in question:

```
.content-header {
    background-image: url ('../images/first_page_slideshow.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;      
    width: 1024px;
    height: 380px;      
}
```

Yet I the image fails to load as a background.  Google developer tools reveals that it is an "Invalid Property Value" on the background-image: css tag.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
background-image: url ('../images/first_page_slideshow.png');
```

becomes

```
background-image: url('../images/first_page_slideshow.png');
```

Just a space between `url` and the parenthesis.

A simple proof: http://jsfiddle.net/suLNk/

Comment: Always the simple stuff.  Thanks Kevin.